# Filter data in dataset using LINQ and get result as list of strings

Tags: c#, linq

I have dataset. I am trying to filter it on specific conditions:

1. Column **"display_name"** has values of length **7**
2. Column **"display_name"** has values starting with **'N'**
3. Column "display_name" has values from **1** to **6** characters i.e **substr(1,6)** consists of any character from 0 to 9
4. Then I want to return filtered result in list.

My code is as below:

```
 List<DataRow> filteredRows = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                  .Where(x => (x.Field<string>("Display_name").Length==7) && (x.Field<string>("Display_name").StartsWith("N"))
```

Not able to get correct linq query. My first day of linq, so maybe I am not doing it right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are not selecting a `List<DataRow>` but  `IEnumerable<DataRow>`. That's why your code does not even compile.

I think this is your query:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> query = 
  from row in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
  let name = row.Field<string>("Display_name")
  where name.Length == 7 && name.StartsWith("N") && name.Skip(1).Take(6).All(char.IsDigit)
  select row;
```

If you want a new `List<DataRow>`:

```
List<DataRow> rowList = query.ToList();
```

If you want a new `DataTable`:

```
DataTable table = query.CopyToDataTable(); // throws an exception if no rows available
```

Comment: I tried same. I got string does not contain definition of "Skip"

Comment: @ubaidashraf: you need to add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your code file.

Comment: I also tried  name.Substring(1,6).ALL(char.IsDigit)  , but it showed ALL is not supported for string

Comment: It's `Enumerable.All` and it should work since `string` implements `IEnumerable<Char>`.

Comment: I was using system.data.linq. Changed that to system.linq and it worked